# Error Importing a .dmp file in AWS RDS Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle11g, amazon-rds, datapump

I have followed the [AWS Importing Data into RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html) guide.

I have copied the `.dmp` file from Source Oracle Instance on another machine to the `DATA_DUMP_DIR` on RDS Instance.

Now I am trying to import it using the code below:

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'sample_copied.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''CORE_API'',''CORE_DAP'', ''CORE_MD'', ''CORE_ST'', ''CORE_BI'', ''CORE_MAPI'', ''CORE_MAPI_LOG'', ''CORE_LEG'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(hdnl,'REMAP_TABLESPACE','LOG','STORAGE_DATA');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(hdnl,'REMAP_TABLESPACE','CORE_LEG_TBS','LEG_DATA');
dbms_datapump.metadata_transform ( hdnl, 'OID' , 0 , null ) ;
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
/
```

When I execute above in `sqlplus`, I get:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3507
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 3756
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

How do I get the above to work? AWS Doc is very abstract & rest of the stuff I found isn't helping either.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127393/data-pump-throws-an-error

Comment: Please,  list the files in the DATA_PUMP_DIR using `select * from table(RDSADMIN.RDS_FILE_UTIL.LISTDIR('DATA_PUMP_DIR')) order by mtime;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)Connect to the RDS instance with the Amazon RDS master user account.

2) Run this pl/sql block

```
    DECLARE
    hdnl NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'sample_copied.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''CORE_API'',''CORE_DAP'', ''CORE_MD'', ''CORE_ST'', ''CORE_BI'', ''CORE_MAPI'', ''CORE_MAPI_LOG'', ''CORE_LEG'')');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(hdnl,'REMAP_TABLESPACE','LOG','STORAGE_DATA');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_REMAP(hdnl,'REMAP_TABLESPACE','CORE_LEG_TBS','LEG_DATA');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
    END;

/
```

3) You can start importing from a Source Oracle Instance.
Example

```
impdp RDS_master_user/password@rds_instance DUMPFILE=sample_copied.dmp   DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR parfile=import_parfile
```

import_parfile

```
REMAP_TABLESPACE=LOG:STORAGE_DATA
REMAP_TABLESPACE=CORE_LEG_TBS:LEG_DATA
SCHEMAS =CORE_API,CORE_DAP,CORE_MD,CORE_ST,CORE_BI,CORE_MAPI,CORE_MAPI_LOG, CORE_LEG
```

Comment: Thanks for briefly describing the answer!