# Error while importing oracle dump using DBMS_DATAPUMP in oracle 12g

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I have been trying to import a dump file into Oracle 12g under RDS in AWS and getting below error all the time and I can't figure it out on what is happening. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here is what I am trying to do.

1) I got a `.dat` dump file from customer (not sure how they have exported this dump from oracle) and my aim is to import this to AWS oracle RDS instance.

2) As per [How to transfer Oracle dump file to AWS RDS instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378147/how-to-transfer-oracle-dump-file-to-aws-rds-instance)

I have created new EC2 instance and installed Oracle Express edition and then copied .dat file to DATA_PUMP_DIR directory (`/u01/app/oracle/admin/XE/dpdump/`).

3) Created database link to AWS oracle RDS instance and able to copy this to rds instance using `DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.PUT_FILE`.

4) I can see the file under DATA_PUMP_DIR path in oracle rds instance.

so far so good.

5) Now, I am trying to import the dump file into RDS using below procedure

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name => null);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'sample.dat', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
/
```

**All the time I get below error**

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4087
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4338
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

I understand the error is pointing to the line `DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE()` but I could not able to make out what is wrong here.

I have tried various options to import but none helped. I have created tablespace and also make sure user is having correct permissions.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48398623/error-importing-a-dmp-file-in-aws-rds-oracle-db/48404625#48404625

Comment: Sorry. that is not helping and in my case I have the dump file already moved to rds. As I mentioned in my post, I don't know the dump file is generated by customer. All I am trying to do is to blindly import that into rds. Is it something possible in first place? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

1)Connect to the RDS instance with the Amazon RDS master user account.

2) Run this pl/sql block

```
    DECLARE
    hdnl NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'sample_copied.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''SCHEMA_NAME'')');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
    END;

/
```

3) You can start importing from any oracle client. For example, Instance EC2.

```
impdp RDS_master_user/password@rds_instance DUMPFILE=sample.dmp   DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR parfile=import_parfile
```

import_parfile

```
SCHEMAS =SCHEMA_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. I am getting error mention in my post when performing step (2) in your response.